# TBPF_INDETERMINATE status has no effect in .NET 2.0 on Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: vb.net, winapi, windows-7, .net-2.0, taskbar

I have a very weird problem. I have a VB.NET 2.0 application that takes advantage of Windows 7 taskbar button progress features, i.e. displaying certain progress and application state in the Win7 taskbar button.

Everything works just fine - I can set and update progress, I can set the button to paused or ewrror state, I can set it to No progress. Everything works, except MARQUE (Indeterminate) mode. This is a total mistery, whenever I set state to TBPF_INDETERMINATE (value of 0x1), it simply changes back to NOPROGRESS type, i.e. it removes all progress inidcation from the taskbar button and sets it back to its default state - no animated marque is ever displayed!

I have read documentation on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391697(v=vs.85).aspx ; tried various combinations like setting progress to 0 and then calling set state to indeterminate; or like setting it to normal first and then to indeterminate - nothing works. It's a total mistery - and there is no clue in the documentation as to why it is failing...

Here's the code:
The API implementation:

```
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure RECT
    Public left As Integer
    Public top As Integer
    Public right As Integer
    Public bottom As Integer

    Public Sub New(left As Integer, top As Integer, right As Integer, bottom As Integer)
        Me.left = left
        Me.top = top
        Me.right = right
        Me.bottom = bottom
    End Sub
End Structure

Public Enum TBPFLAG
    TBPF_NOPROGRESS = 0
    TBPF_INDETERMINATE = &H1
    TBPF_NORMAL = &H2
    TBPF_ERROR = &H4
    TBPF_PAUSED = &H8
End Enum

Public Enum TBATFLAG
    TBATF_USEMDITHUMBNAIL = &H1
    TBATF_USEMDILIVEPREVIEW = &H2
End Enum

Public Enum THBMASK
    THB_BITMAP = &H1
    THB_ICON = &H2
    THB_TOOLTIP = &H4
    THB_FLAGS = &H8
End Enum

Public Enum THBFLAGS
    THBF_ENABLED = 0
    THBF_DISABLED = &H1
    THBF_DISMISSONCLICK = &H2
    THBF_NOBACKGROUND = &H4
    THBF_HIDDEN = &H8
End Enum

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Structure THUMBBUTTON
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
    Public dwMask As THBMASK
    Public iId As UInteger
    Public iBitmap As UInteger
    Public hIcon As IntPtr
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)> _
    Public szTip As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
    Public dwFlags As THBFLAGS
End Structure

<ComImportAttribute()> _
<GuidAttribute("ea1afb91-9e28-4b86-90e9-9e9f8a5eefaf")> _
<InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
Public Interface ITaskbarList3
    ' ITaskbarList
    <PreserveSig()> _
    Sub HrInit()
    <PreserveSig()> _
    Sub AddTab(hwnd As IntPtr)
    <PreserveSig()> _
    Sub DeleteTab(hwnd As IntPtr)
    <PreserveSig()> _
    Sub ActivateTab(hwnd As IntPtr)
    <PreserveSig()> _
    Sub SetActiveAlt(hwnd As IntPtr)

    ' ITaskbarList2
    <PreserveSig()> _
    Sub MarkFullscreenWindow(hwnd As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> fFullscreen As Boolean)

    ' ITaskbarList3
    Sub SetProgressValue(<[In]()> ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, <[In]()> ByVal ullCompleted As UInt64, <[In]()> ByVal ullTotal As UInt64) 'hwnd As IntPtr, ullCompleted As UInt64, ullTotal As UInt64)
    Sub SetProgressState(<[In]()> ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, <[In]()> ByVal tbpFlags As TBPFLAG) 'hwnd As IntPtr, tbpFlags As TBPFLAG) 'As Integer
    Sub RegisterTab(hwndTab As IntPtr, hwndMDI As IntPtr)
    Sub UnregisterTab(hwndTab As IntPtr)
    Sub SetTabOrder(hwndTab As IntPtr, hwndInsertBefore As IntPtr)
    Sub SetTabActive(hwndTab As IntPtr, hwndMDI As IntPtr, tbatFlags As TBATFLAG)
    Sub ThumbBarAddButtons(hwnd As IntPtr, cButtons As UInteger, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> pButtons As THUMBBUTTON())
    Sub ThumbBarUpdateButtons(hwnd As IntPtr, cButtons As UInteger, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> pButtons As THUMBBUTTON())
    Sub ThumbBarSetImageList(hwnd As IntPtr, himl As IntPtr)
    Sub SetOverlayIcon(hwnd As IntPtr, hIcon As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszDescription As String)
    Sub SetThumbnailTooltip(hwnd As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszTip As String)
    '[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    Sub SetThumbnailClip(hwnd As IntPtr, ByRef prcClip As RECT)
End Interface

<GuidAttribute("56FDF344-FD6D-11d0-958A-006097C9A090")> _
<ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
<ComImportAttribute()> _
Public Class CTaskbarList
End Class
```

And here are the actual procedures that use the code:

```
 Friend Sub SetWindows7Progress(ByVal aValue As Integer)
        If Not IsWin7orLater Then Exit Sub
            If w7tb Is Nothing Then
                w7tb = CType(New CTaskbarList, ITaskbarList3)
            End If
            CType(w7tb, ITaskbarList3).SetProgressValue(My.Forms.Form1.Handle, Math.Min(Math.Max(1, aValue), 1000), 1000)
 End Sub

    Friend Sub ResetWindows7Progress()
        If Not IsWin7orLater Then Exit Sub
            If w7tb Is Nothing Then
                w7tb = CType(New CTaskbarList, ITaskbarList3)
            End If
            CType(w7tb, ITaskbarList3).SetProgressState(My.Forms.Form1.Handle, TBPFLAG.TBPF_NOPROGRESS)
    End Sub

    Friend Sub SetWindows7ProgressMon()
        If Not IsWin7orLater Then Exit Sub
            If w7tb Is Nothing Then
                w7tb = CType(New CTaskbarList, ITaskbarList3)
            End If
            CType(w7tb, ITaskbarList3).SetProgressState(My.Forms.Form1.Handle, TBPF_INDETERMINATE)
    End Sub
```

I even tried getting the HRESULT code from SetProgressState and checking to make sure no exception is thrown to no avail: SetProgressState always returns 0 (everything is fine); and no exceptions are thrown!

Any help in resolving the matter would be greatly appreciated! I just can't believe that everything works except the MARQUE/INDETERMINATE state!

Thanks.

Comment: Is the code from the Windows API Code Pack? Or did you write the p/invoke definitions yourself from the docs on MSDN?

Comment: Both - I took the Windows API Code Pack, and basically kept just the ITaskbarList3 together with a couple of additional structures/enums (that are used by the ITaskbarList3); and then I converted that small code from C# to VB.NET - pretty straight-forward - I have included all that code with this post.

Comment: BTW the reason for doing it was that: 1) My app is .NET 2.0, while the API code pack requires .net 3.5; and 2) I really needed just the progress buttons feature - and did not need any others.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I was mainly curious so that I'd know how much of the code I needed to check for errors. I decided it would be easier just to fire up Visual Studio and test it myself. I think I've identified the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** it's very strange that your worker functions are accessing your form's instance using this code:

```
 My.Forms.Form1.Handle
```

That implies that those functions are *not* defined in the same class as your form (because if they were, the compiler would prompt you to use `Me`, instead). And if that's the case, you really should be passing the handle to the form into the function as a parameter.

(The reason for this is so that your functions are reusable. If you hardcode a reference to a particular form, what happens when you rename that form, or display two instances of it on the screen at a time, or just want to show a progress indicator in the taskbar for a different form? Things break. Passing the form instance as a parameter is a much cleaner, more reusable approach.)

**Second,** there seems like an unnecessary amount of casting going on. Why not just declare the `w7tb` variable as type `ITaskbarList3` in the first place, rather than casting back and forth between that and `CTaskbarList`?

**Third,** I'm not sure if this is a typo or the actual problem, but your `SetWindows7ProgressMon` function does not actually reference the correct value for `TBPF_INDETERMINATE`. You use an unqualified reference to that identifier, when it's *actually* defined in the `TBPFLAG` enumeration.

So, considering all of the above, I would rewrite the second block of code that you posted as follows:

```
Private w7tb As ITaskbarList3

Friend Sub SetWindows7Progress(ByVal frm As Form, ByVal aValue As Integer)
    If (Not IsWin7orLater()) OrElse (frm Is Nothing) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If w7tb Is Nothing Then
        w7tb = CType(New CTaskbarList, ITaskbarList3)
    End If
    w7tb.SetProgressValue(frm.Handle, Math.Min(Math.Max(1, aValue), 1000), 1000)
End Sub

Friend Sub ResetWindows7Progress(ByVal frm As Form)
    If (Not IsWin7orLater()) OrElse (frm Is Nothing) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If w7tb Is Nothing Then
        w7tb = CType(New CTaskbarList, ITaskbarList3)
    End If
    w7tb.SetProgressState(frm.Handle, TBPFLAG.TBPF_NOPROGRESS)
End Sub

Friend Sub SetWindows7ProgressMon(ByVal frm As Form)
    If (Not IsWin7orLater()) OrElse (frm Is Nothing) Then
       Exit Sub
    End If

    If w7tb Is Nothing Then
        w7tb = CType(New CTaskbarList, ITaskbarList3)
    End If
    w7tb.SetProgressState(frm.Handle, TBPFLAG.TBPF_INDETERMINATE)
End Sub
```

This is tested to work perfectly on Windows 7 32-bit. Note that you can call the functions from code inside of your form class by simply specifying `Me` for the `frm` parameter.

Comment: @Cody Wow you are so fast! Thanks a lot for looking into this. I will try your 1 and 2 suggestions, although in terms of code, though clealrly they are better and cleanerr, but shouldn;'t they be equivalent to the code I have? (i.e. they should not be a problem). As for #3 - it was a typo (because I tried putting there all sorts of things like the actuial value #1 or things like "1 or 2" - nothing worked - so #3 is a typo (as I corrected code on this website) and it really is TBPFLAG.TBPF_INDETERMINATE as you wrote in my code, and it does not work :( ) But I will test your 1 and 2 suggestions.

Comment: @George: Yeah, the casting will be completely irrelevant to the end result. The way you find a reference to your form class, not necessarily. But that'd probably make it not work at all, so I assume you would have noticed in applying the other styles. I was afraid it might be a typo... I'm honestly not sure what else could be the problem. The code I showed (combined with your p/invoke declarations) works fine on my MacBook Pro running Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit.

Comment: Well, just tried #1 and #2 - now it does not work at all. I think the culprit is your suggestion #2 - you really need to create an INSTANCE of iTaskBarList3, and the way to do it is have that intermediate class - CTaskbarList - after all it should serve some purpose with it's GUID, shouldn't it?

Comment: BTW My OS is Win7 Ultimate 32 bit as well. Could the problem have to do with the fact that I am testing it from within Visual Studio?

Comment: @George: You can't actually create an instance of an interface. You can only create an instance of a class that *implements* an interface. That class is `CTaskbarList`. And thanks to polymorphism, any class that implements an interface can be cast to and from that interface. `CTaskbarList` isn't an "intermediate" class, it's the only class that's defined. The changes I've made can't possibly make any difference. You're still using the GUID metadata because you're still instantiating `CTaskbarList` with this code: `CType(New CTaskbarList, ITaskbarList3)`. The `New CTaskbarList` is what does it.

Comment: And no, Visual Studio can't be the explanation. I ran it from both inside and outside of VS. Maybe edit your question to include the syntax you're using to *call* those functions in your form class? That's the only thing that could possibly be different between the two versions.

Comment: @Cody Oh, and BTW I do get the Marquee feature on my Win7 from other programs like Far Manager, so it's not like my Win7 is defective in this way...

Comment: @Cody Yes, you are right I forgot to instantiate 'w7tb'. So I have now completely implemented your code, as you posted above, and the problem remains - everything works except marquee mode. Yikes!

Comment: @George: I just thought I'd check back in and see if you were ever able to resolve the problem. I tested the code I posted on a couple of different machines (Win 7 32-bit, Win 7 64-bit, Server 2008 R2 64-bit), and I have absolutely no problem getting the "marquee" mode to work. I even set my project to target .NET 2.0. It seems there must either be something wrong with your code or something weird about your machine. First thing I'd try is to create a brand new, blank project, and copy and paste the code I have (plus the P/Invoke definitions from your question), and see if it works.

Comment: @Cody Thanks for testing that! Yep, that's what I will do ASAP and when have the results will let you know. I kind of think that there must be something wrong either with my machine or the project (VS 2010 SP1 Pro, VB.NET WinForms App .NET 2.0 on Win7 32 bit). Though I more in favor of the later, since the marque mode does work for other apps on my machine...

Comment: @Cody Just confirmed: it does not work with absolutely empty and new .NET 2.0 VB project. Is there a way I can send this empty zipped project to you for you to test?

Comment: @Cody Just tested this new project on Win7 32 bit VM and it worked - so there seems to be some issue with my dev machine, however I have no clue what it may be as other apps do work. I guess it's now a question for superuser.com :)

Comment: @George: Very strange that it wouldn't work with some apps, but does work with others. I'm not sure if anyone will have an answer for you on Super User, but it doesn't hurt to ask. I'm out of ideas; the code is written correctly and even confirmed to work for you on a VM.

Comment: @Cody Yeah...perhaps its some bug in Windows API that should be reported to Microsoft? But the good thing is that it works on most computers which is what I really care about. Thank you for all your help!